# How to not use __init__.py as Flask app name?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app structured like so:

- repo_root

  - config.py
  - requirements.txt
  - my_cool_app/
  - my_cool_app/__init__.py
  - my_cool_app/models.py
  - my_cool_app/views.py
  - my_cool_app/static/
  - my_cool_app/templates/

And the contents of *my_cool_app/__init__.py* looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_oauth2_login import GoogleLogin
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

google_login = GoogleLogin(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

import my_cool_app.models
import my_cool_app.views
```

To run it, I invoke:

```
FLASK_APP=my_cool_app/__init__.py flask run
```

Based on a variety of documentation online, I thought I should be able to just set `FLASK_APP` to the package name `my_cool_app`. When I do this, and invoke `flask run`, the application starts but in the browser I immediately see the error:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: The file/path provided (my_cool_app) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

What should I be doing to be able to set the `FLASK_APP` to just `my_cool_app`? Or is it more appropriate/typical for `FLASK_APP` to be set to something else, given the way this flask application is structured?

Comment: What directory are you in when you execute your export FLASK_APP=my_cool_app flask run?  Are  you in your repo_root directory?

Comment: In general `__init__.py` is a good place to put code that is required to initial a package. It's not a goid place to put application code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion surrounding [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1847), it seems that one can indeed set `FLASK_APP=my_cool_app` and run successfully with `python -m flask run`. Not yet sure how this impacts a production config.

Comment: Doing this causes a warning /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'flask.cli' found in sys.modules after import of package 'flask', but prior to execution of 'flask.cli'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your my_cool_app module isn't getting picked up in your python path.  If it's not, you'd need to set your PYTHONPATH variable as well.

Assuming you're in the repo_root directory when executing your command, you should be able to use:

```
FLASK_APP=my_cool_app PYTHONPATH=. flask run
```

If you want to run it from anywhere, then:

```
FLASK_APP=my_cool_app PYTHONPATH=/path/to/repo flask run
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'd like to avoid changing PYTHONPATH if possible, to adhere to better practices. See https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1847

Comment: Seems that `python -m flask run` might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "circular" imports in your views.py and model.py. So at the top you should have a line like this

```
from my_cool_app import app
```

Overall, the structure of the application looks really good and follows what flask recommends for larger applications. For more information, try to follow this link http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/. They seem to have an example with a similar structure to that of your app and they walk you through how to export all the environment variables and get the package running.